# Set content type by workflow

Tags: list, content-type, copy-item

I need to set Content Type by workflow.  However, SP Designer does not give the option to do this.  I am copying a content type item from one list to another.  I can not Set the content type either in the source or the destination list; SP copies the item, but uses the default content type in the destination list (this is the wrong one for me!).

### Background and purpose

Users submit forms to a public list.  I have a workflow to copy the item to a 'private' HR list, where HR will manage the items.  The HR list has 2x content types.  Unfortunately, when the new item is created in the HR list it is created using the List default **ContentType1** instead of **ContentType2**.

Unable to Set content type in Designer.  I tried using Designer to Set content type both in the source and the destination list, but to no avail.

[image: Content Type does not appear as an available field in SP Designer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going about it in the wrong way.

1. Use 'Create Item', select the Destination list (mine is called OH light).
2. On the 'Content Type ID' the value is currently 'item' (which is my destination list default).  Modify the value to the one you want - in my case I need to select HealthSafety OH' as my content type.

[image]